# How can you setup a rspec view spec so that render is only called once for all of its specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rspec

I have the following view spec:

```
describe "carts/show" do
  before(:each) do
    book = build_stubbed(:product, title: "book")
    car = build_stubbed(:product, title: "car")
    line_item1 = build_stubbed(:line_item, product: book, quantity: 3)
    line_item2 = build_stubbed(:line_item, product: car, quantity: 1)
    @cart = assign(:cart, build_stubbed(:cart, line_items: [line_item1, line_item2]))
    render
  end

  it "displays a single car" do
    assert_select "li", text: "1 time: car"
  end
  it "displays 3 books" do
    assert_select "li", text: "3 times: book"
  end
  it "has exactly 2 items" do
    assert_select "li", 2
  end

end
```

This specs works as expected. However, because the setup is in a `before(:each)` block, the setup and `render` method is called once per it block. This is pretty slow. Ideally, they should only be called once for the whole `describe` block.

I thought changing `before(:each)` to `before(:all)` would fix this, but I got the error (line 16 in show.html.erb_spec.rb is the `render` call):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `example_group' for nil:NilClass
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-rails-2.12.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/view_example_group.rb:106:in `_default_file_to_render'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-rails-2.12.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/view_example_group.rb:112:in `_default_render_options'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-rails-2.12.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/view_example_group.rb:45:in `render'
show.html.erb_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:23:in `instance_eval'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:23:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:424:in `run_hook'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:319:in `run_before_all_hooks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:368:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.12.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I don't know what else I could do here. What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: maybe this will help. move all the 'it' under a 'context'. so it will be called only once for each context.

Comment: @surase.prasad: Didn't help unfortunately. `before(:each)` is called once per spec, even if the specs are in an inner context.

Comment: in the above spec, u intend to check that all the items(car, books) etc are to be displayed in the cart and on the same page. so, y dont u  check all the above 'assert_select' in a single 'it' condition. its a better check since ur cases may pass individually but they need to pass as a whole(considering that all the items are present in SINGLE cart)

Comment: It's nice to split the specs apart to help document what's going on - but yeah, collapsing them into one spec would be a way to solve this

Comment: Yes, merging all of the specs fixes it, but I would prefer to do it the "right" way if possible - especially if I move away from assert_select and start using rspec matchers for this job.

Comment: You should be able to use rspec expectations even w/ what you have now - they just layer on top

Answer (score 2):

RSpec-Rails' rendering definitely assumes that it occurs within each test, which is going to make this a little awkward, and we need to play around with internal state from the looks of it.

From poking around rspec-rails, it looks like it delegates its `render` call to [`ActionView::TestCase::Behavior#render`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/test_case.rb#L113).  `@rendered` seems to be the state that matters (and probably `@view`), but I have no idea whether this will introduce even more gotchas.

Here's my completely untested approach:

```
describe "carts/show" do

  # Memoize the view across test runs for speed; this is some dangerous
  # spelunking in internal state, though!
  rendered_view    = nil
  rendered_content = nil

  before(:each) do
    if rendered_view && rendered_content
      @view     = rendered_view
      @rendered = rendered_content
    else
      book = build_stubbed(:product, title: "book")
      car = build_stubbed(:product, title: "car")
      line_item1 = build_stubbed(:line_item, product: book, quantity: 3)
      line_item2 = build_stubbed(:line_item, product: car, quantity: 1)
      @cart = assign(:cart, build_stubbed(:cart, line_items: [line_item1, line_item2]))

      render

      rendered_view    = @view
      rendered_content = @rendered
    end
  end

  it "displays a single car" do
    assert_select "li", text: "1 time: car"
  end
  it "displays 3 books" do
    assert_select "li", text: "3 times: book"
  end
  it "has exactly 2 items" do
    assert_select "li", 2
  end

end
```

Comment: That works! However I'm a bit dubious of using such a hack though. I really thought there would be a simple way to do this. Rspec is really popular in the rails world, surely other people have had this problem before :/. Or maybe the render call isn't expensive enough to be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal, but you can use the [`shared_subject`](https://gist.github.com/dnagir/c47aba850d5a3adf931d)

To use it you essentially:

1. Replace 'subject' with 'shared_subject' to share the first result acrooss the whole context.
2. (optional) replace 'before(:each)' blocks with 'shared_setup'
3. Done. The subject will be shared within one, single context (nested will be re-setup again).

So your example will look like:

```
describe "carts/show" do
  shared_subject do
    book = build_stubbed(:product, title: "book")
    car = build_stubbed(:product, title: "car")
    line_item1 = build_stubbed(:line_item, product: book, quantity: 3)
    line_item2 = build_stubbed(:line_item, product: car, quantity: 1)
    @cart = assign(:cart, build_stubbed(:cart, line_items: [line_item1, line_item2]))
    render
  end

  it "displays a single car" do
    assert_select "li", text: "1 time: car"
  end
  it "displays 3 books" do
    assert_select "li", text: "3 times: book"
  end
  it "has exactly 2 items" do
    assert_select "li", 2
  end

end
```